# Forcing Java generic parameters to be of the same type

Tags: java, generics

How can a similar functionality be achieved without errors?

```
class A<K> {
   void f(K x) {}
}

void foo(A<? extends X> a, X x) {
    a.f(x); // AN error: The method f(capture#1-of ? extends X) in the 
            // type A<capture#1-of ? extends X> is not applicable for the 
            // arguments (X)
}
```

I know that it happens because 'a' can be an instance of A<"non-X">, so its 'f' mustn't accept an instance of X as a parameter, but how can I force the parameters to be of the same type?

Here is more code:

Test class:

```
class Test {
   <T> void foo(A<T> a, T x) {
   a.f(x); // now it works!
 }
}
```

In some class:

```
Container<X> container;
public void test() {
    X x = new X();
    new Test().foo(container.get(), x);
}
```

Here's the container class:

```
public class Container<K> {
    A<? extends K> get() {
    return new A<K>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is X a class or a type parameter?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can *force the parameters to be of the same type* by doing the following:

```
// the first class, A<K>:
class A<K> {
  void f(K x) {}
}

// the second class, defining the method with generic type parameters
class Test {
  <T> void foo(A<T> a, T x) {
    a.f(x); // now it works!
  }
}

// a third class, that uses the above two:
class Main {
  public static void main(final String... args) {
    final Test test = new Test();
    final A<String> a = new A<>();
    test.foo(a, "bar");
  }
}
```

What this does is: the method `foo` defines a generic type parameter `T` and uses it to enforce that the `K` type parameter of the class `A` must match the type of `x`, the second parameter of `foo`.

You could even impose restrictions on `<T>` if you wish and if it makes sense for your problem, such as `<T extends Bar> void foo(A<T> a, T x) {...}`, or with `super`. You would want this if, as *Joni* asked on a comment in the question, `X` is actually a type and not a type parameter: you'd use `<T extends X> void foo(...)`.

---

After you've shown more code, the problem becomes clear.

The method `.get()` of the container returns an instance of `A<? extends K>`. Therefore, the type parameter of the instance you obtain from `.get()` is not fully specified. Usually, it is not very good design to return such an unspecified type. For a video presentation with Joshua Bloch, the author of Effective Java and many APIs and features in Java, showing how to improve such an API, check this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1vQf4qyMXg&feature=youtu.be&t=22m. At exactly 25'36", Joshua Bloch says "don't try to use them [wildcard types] on return values", and he explains it later. Basically, you don't get any more flexibility by using them, and just makes it painfully hard for users of the API to deal with it (you just felt the effects of doing it...).

To fix, you could simply try to change the signature of `.get()` to `A<K> get()`, so the container class would be:

```
public class Container<K> {
  A<K> get() {
    return new A<K>();
  }
}
```

Since you do know that `get()` is returning an instance of `A<K>`, there's no reason to use the older signature: it simply makes you lose information you already know!

And if this still doesn't work, your problem might be somewhere else, and you'd need to show even more code... or better still, ask other questions! :)

Comment: But how can it be used?
`new Test().foo(a, x);` still returns an error: 
The method foo(A<T>, T) in the type A<K>.Test is not applicable for the arguments (A<capture#1-of ? extends X>, X)

Comment: You seem to be defining the class `Test` as an inner class of `A`, which is not exactly what I've shown above.

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter: The error now is `The method foo(A<T>, T) in the type Test is not applicable for the arguments (A<capture#1-of ? extends X>, X)`

Comment: It looks to me like the compiler isn't certain whether the variable `a` is of type `A<X>` or `A<? extends X>`. If you're passing an `X` into that function, you have to make sure that `a` is of type `A<X>`. What type is it, specifically?

Comment: How exactly are you obtaining the instance you are passing as the first parameter to `.foo(...)`? The problem seems to be there: the static type of `a` doesn't seem to match `A<T>`. You need to show more code.

Answer (score 6):

Keeping in mind the [PECS rule](http://books.google.hr/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=effective+java+pecs&source=bl&ots=yYJhNnu_M1&sig=PUM7fjtq0tDDnmPGYBM02H6fHrc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=civQUeDsAsj4sgbylYDoCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=effective%20java%20pecs&f=false), and given the way you are using X, you should be specifying as a *lower* instead of upper bound:

```
void foo(A<? super X> a, X x)
```

This way no compiler errors are produced, and you have the most general signature applicable.

Comment: This is not exactly what the question says: the OP asks for a way to make `X` be the *same* type on both `A<X> a` and `X x`. Maybe he does want what you answered, but the question should be rephrased then.

Comment: OP also asks "How can a similar functionality be achieved without errors?" - and Marko's answer does just that.

Comment: @meriton, indeed. But that seems a little bit too vague, unspecified.

Comment: @BrunoReis Since, for example, a `String` *is-an* `Object`, they are of the same type, at least in the sense relevant to OP's use case.