# How can I force two instance variables to be of the same generic type?

Tags: java, generics

Assuming I have a class with two instance variables of generic type, how can I force those types to be the same?

I haven't found any similar questions elsewhere (let alone answers), which may be because I'm using terms wrong. There's [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390441/forcing-java-generic-parameters-to-be-of-the-same-type), but I'm not sure how to apply it to my situation.

In short, how can I get this last line of code to not compile?

```
class Foo<T> {
    private T value;
}

class Bar {
    private Foo var1;
    private Foo var2;

    public Bar(Foo var1, Foo var2) {
        this.var1 = var1;
        this.var2 = var2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo<String> var1 = new Foo<>();
        Foo<Integer> var2 = new Foo<>();
        Bar b = new Bar(var1, var2); // this should not work
    }
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Make `Bar` also generic:

```
class Bar<T> {
    private Foo<T> var1;
    private Foo<T> var2;

    public Bar(Foo<T> var1, Foo<T> var2) {
        this.var1 = var1;
        this.var2 = var2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo<String> var1 = new Foo<>();
        Foo<Integer> var2 = new Foo<>();
        Bar<String> b = new Bar<>(var1, var2); // this does not work
    }
}
```

By using a class level generic parameter `T` for `Bar` you can enforce the same types for both instance variables.

This eliminates also the warning of using raw types ([which should never be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)) as mentioned by @daniu in the comments.

---

Now if you happen to not use raw types *but* want to allow not the same types, you can work with wildcards:

With upper bounded, which only allow typed reading (`var1` and `var2` will always produce an implementation of type `T`):

```
class Bar<T> {
    private Foo<? extends T> var1;
    private Foo<? extends T> var2;

    public Bar(Foo<? extends T> var1, Foo<? extends T> var2) {
        this.var1 = var1;
        this.var2 = var2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo<String> var1 = new Foo<>();
        Foo<Integer> var2 = new Foo<>();
        Bar<Object> b = new Bar<>(var1, var2); // this does now work
    }
}
```

And with lower bounded, which only allow typed writing (`var1` and `var2` will always consume any implementation of type `T`):

```
class Bar<T> {
    private Foo<? super T> var1;
    private Foo<? super T> var2;

    public Bar(Foo<? super T> var1, Foo<? super T> var2) {
        this.var1 = var1;
        this.var2 = var2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo<Integer> var1 = new Foo<>();
        Foo<Number> var2 = new Foo<>();
        Bar<Integer> b = new Bar<>(var1, var2); // this does now work
    }
}
```

For more on that topic you can read: [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Comment: The `var1` and `var2` declared with raw `Foo` type give a compiler warning in the OP's code anyway, this is the only way around it.

Answer (score 3):

Lino's answer is good. I want to add one fact:

If you don't have to keep track of the type of the `var`s, but only verify that they are of the same type, then you can move the type parameter from the `Bar` class to its constructor:

```
class Bar {
    // These will always have the same type, but
    // that's not visible here
    private Foo<?> var1;
    private Foo<?> var2;

    // The parameter types of the construct ensures that
    // the vars are always of the same type
    public <T> Bar(Foo<T> var1, Foo<T> var2) {
        this.var1 = var1;
        this.var2 = var2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo<String> var1 = new Foo<>();
        Foo<Integer> var2 = new Foo<>();

        Bar b1 = new Bar(var1, var1); // Works fine
        Bar b2 = new Bar(var1, var2); // Compilation error
    }
}
```

This technique works for all kinds of methods.

Comment: Good point! Although you can't really do anything with `var1` and `var2` because from the `value`-member of `Foo` you'll just get `Object` when you read it, and you can't write to it (Not a problem if you just invoke methods from `Foo`)